# How to Toggle Bluetooth in All Android Versions 1.5+ and Upwards

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to write a simple android application to toggle a users bluetooth connection.  I would like a single application that can work on all versions of Android 1.5+.

I am aware that the Android 2+ API officially added support for bluetooth however if I am targeting a SDK level of 3 (android 1.5) then I don't get access to the official BluetoothAdapter classes.

I have seen some examples on the web that use reflection and this will work on 1.5 and 1.6 but not 2.0.

I have also seen the following unoffical bluetooth API's however neither of their example apps (available in the market as "Bluetooth Samples" and "backport-android-bluetooth") work on my Nexus One.

http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/
http://code.google.com/p/backport-android-bluetooth/

Does anyone have some sample code that will work on ALL versions of Android?

I know it is possible to achieve bluetooth toggling in a single app and for versions 1.5+ because there are many applications on the market, that I have tested and are able to achieve this.

Any help is really appreciated and thanks for reading.

NOTE: Please don't just suggest writing separate apps targeting different versions, this is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: you don't have to use differnt apps, you can read the api version from the code and adapt your code ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am aware I can determine the API version at runtime and run version specific code per device.  
Unfortunately I haven't got the code that can enable/disable bluetooth on a version 2+ device using the native API targeted for API level 3.  Please share if you know how to achieve this.

Comment: What's stopping you from checking the API version at runtime and then determining which method to use? If you've already got code that works on the older versions, and official APIs that do what you want are introduced for the newer versions, then what's the issue? Just set min SDK version to 3, but target the level when the new Bluetooth classes were released. Before trying to use a higher-than-api-3 class, check the system version.

Comment: I had assumed that setting the minSdkVersion property lower than the projects target api would cause issues. I will give it a try however and let you know how I get on. Thanks Steve.

Comment: As suspected the application instantly force closes on a G1 (v1.6) with "application <namespace> has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."  

  All my code is surrounded with try catch blocks and debug toast messages so I can only assume this is caused because its not targeting the right API.  

Works on a Nexus one however.

Comment: I've just found some additional documentation (link below) so I'm gonna experiment with the "targetSdkVersion" attribute tonight and see if that helps at all.  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html. Bluetooth Adapter has been around since Eclair. However, there is no way of doing this before then unless an intent to the appropriate settings page is opened (as with the following example):

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

I would recommend that you use an intent to the Blueetooth Settings page as this is easier to implement and will identify if bluetooth is avaliable on the device.

I hope this helped.